# runtime error - questão

Tags: python

Neste problema, deve-se ler o código de uma peça 1, o número de peças 1, o valor unitário de cada peça 1, o código de uma peça 2, o número de peças 2 e o valor unitário de cada peça 2. Após, calcule e mostre o valor a ser pago.

**Entrada**

O arquivo de entrada contém duas linhas de dados. Em cada linha haverá 3 valores, respectivamente dois inteiros e um valor com 2 casas decimais.

**Saída**

A saída deverá ser uma mensagem conforme o exemplo fornecido abaixo, lembrando de deixar um espaço após os dois pontos e um espaço após o "R$". O valor deverá ser apresentado com 2 casas após o ponto.

```
código_peça_1 = int(input())
número_peça_1 = int(input())
valor_peça_1 =  float(input())
código_peça_2 = int(input())
número_peça_2 = int(input())
valor_peça_2 =  float(input())
valor_a_pagar = ( número_peça_1 * valor_peça_1 ) + ( número_peça_2 * valor_peça_2 )
print("VALOR A PAGAR = R$ %.2f" %valor_a_pagar)
```

Answer (score 1):

> O arquivo de entrada contém duas linhas de dados.

Então você deve fazer apenas duas leituras da entrada e fazer a divisão dos valores:

```
entrada = input().split()
codigo_1 = int(entrada[0])
quantidade_1 = int(entrada[1])
valor_1 = float(entrada[2])

entrada = input().split()
codigo_2 = int(entrada[0])
quantidade_2 = int(entrada[1])
valor_2 = float(entrada[2])
```

E, assim, calcular o resultado.